# Querying express-cassandra with Uuid types

Tags: uuid, express-cassandra

I'm trying to query cassandra with id but I get this error

> apollo.model.validator.invalidvalue: Invalid Value: "{ id: [Uuid] }" for Field: id (Type: uuid)

In my code I have :

```
const reqId = models.uuidFromString(req.params.id); 
    const queryObj = { id: reqId };  
    this.findById(queryObj, function(err, user)
```

My model:

```
id: {
   type: "uuid",
   rule: {required: true},
   default: {$db_function: "uuid()"}
}
```

Comment: It's difficult to say without knowing the method definition of "findById". Just guessing, you might need to put the reqId directly into findById instead of making a queryObj.

Comment: This is my findById method: exports.findById = (id) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        models.instance.Person.findAsync({id: id})
        .then(function(user) {
            resolve(user.length > 0 ? user[0] : null);
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
            throw err;
         });
    }); 
}

Comment: The problem is that it seems that express-cassandra doesn't recognise the uuid returned from models.uuidFromString(str) method as a valid type which is quite strange to me. This is visible from the error message.

Comment: Nope. From your code and the error message, it is obvious that you are building a query object twice. Hence instead of getting a UUID typed value, express-cassandra is getting an object {id: [UUID]}. Just pass the reqId directly to your findById method like this: `this.findById(reqId, function(err, user)` instead of passing a query object again.

Comment: Thank you alot. Now I see the problem.